# Cross-platform Python Executables

Tags: python, selenium, executable

Is it possible to package together a Python executable that can be run across any platform - provided the correct version of Python is installed?

If, for example, I created a Web Scraping script which included files such as chromium webdriver, the selenium package and other non-builtin Python packages, could I compile some .exe / .jar file that could be sent to a client to run this without having to configure an environment?

Comment: If you build an executable with py2exe there is no need for Python to be installed on the target computer. Making the executable platform-independent is difficult if you need access to the operating system. There are even difficulties for Windows 32 bit and 64 bit. The same code might work however you need to include different libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is mainly cross platform - although I've had experience of reading/writing files being different on Windows/OS X/Linux because of the different directory and file structure (see [Reading and Writing Files](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter8/) for how to cope with that). Cross-platform Python for a GUI application is supposedly harder to do (reference: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2vwm7g/python_for_crossplatform_applications/), I personally have never created a GUI in Python).

It depends on what you want your Python program to do. If you want to install programs and packages then I don't think Python is your answer. Also, Python is not included by default on every system, and even when it is installed, you're not guaranteed to have the correct version running on each system.

This website looks useful for using [Selenium with Python](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html).